# Set value lower than 0 in PHP getting 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some table in my database with column with type BIGINT:
[image]

The problem is, when I set (by update or insert) value lower that 0 (for example -2) then in DB it is set 0.
[image]

Do someone know why?

(I have not any procedures to change this value before insert/update).
Db is MySql

Comment: You're using an unsigned int, which doesn't allow negatives. You can take a read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx regarding bigint in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what your database is actually using is a `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, which has a range of 0 to 18446744073709551615. And according to the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html):

> When an out-of-range value is assigned to an integer column, MySQL stores **the value representing the corresponding endpoint of the column data type range**.

This means that attempting to store a negative number in any `UNSIGNED` column will wrap around to 0.

To remedy this, it's best to explicitly set the data type to be `BIGINT SIGNED`.

Answer (score 4):

You can read the difference between unsigned bigint and signed bigint.
[MySQL Bigint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

Unsigned bigint values are : 0 to 18446744073709551615
Whereas signed bigint values are : -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
So you must use the signed bigint